# hibernate mapping for n number of tables

Tags: database, hibernate

Suppose we have database with 100 or more tables, how can we create corresponding entity classes. Should we create equal number of entity class with respect to number of tables present in database. any particular design pattern to be followed?

Answer (score 0):

the best best wayid to devide your database schema into several main schemas. and for each schema create all necessary classes corresponding to your database tables and relations, the number is not the problem, because having 100 table in database doesn't mean that you have to create 100 class and map each class to a table, you can have 100 class, more than 100 or less, because you might have a relationnal class, or identifier class, or inheritence... etc.

the only thing you should be aware of, is the fact that is realy hard to manipulation relations between those classes to make them represente EXACTLY what you have in database.